# Wordpress Nginx proxy cannot load wp-admin/ajax.php

Tags: ajax, wordpress, nginx, proxy

My website is hosted on 6-cylinder.com
and I decided to add a wordpress blog which is in a completely different VPS. So, I used proxy to list my blog as a subdirectory of my main domain
So the final product should be 6-cylinder.com/blog

The proxy is working completely fine except for one file only!!!!!

```
wp-admin/ajax.php
```

This is the error message in chrome console
[image]

Here is what I added to my wp-config.php

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = str_replace("/wp-admin/", "/blog/wp-admin/",  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://6-cylinder.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://6-cylinder.com/blog' );
```

and here is the proxy code in the nginx file

```
location ^~ /blog/ {
  proxy_pass http://139.59.211.216/;
  proxy_set_header X-Original-Host $host;
  proxy_set_header X-Is-Reverse-Proxy "true";
  proxy_pass_header Set-Cookie;
  proxy_cookie_path / /blog/;
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot host the backend at `http://139.59.211.216/blog/` and avoid all of the rewriting between `/` and `/blog/`?

Comment: No I never even thought of that. Can you elaborate more?

Answer (score 0):

The time i had problems with wp-admin the solution was to add the folowing line to the wp-config.php:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
```

([wordpress behind nginx proxy (acces from two sources)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40061692/wordpress-behind-nginx-proxy-acces-from-two-sources/40193587#40193587))